# Classes PHP que retorna "alerts" css

Tags: php, bootstrap-3, crud

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação pequena que servirá para atualizar meus conhecimentos, porem, no desenvolvimento do mesmo me deparei com algumas situações inconsistentes.
Gostaria que meu "CRUD" retornasse um "div" que exibirá um "alert" css quando executado pelo browser, mas quando executo, somente o alert é exibido e todo o restante do formulário desaparece(executando na mesma página).

database.class.php (projeto inicial, só retorna o erro)

```
// Delete
public function deleteDB($sql,$params=null){
    $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(),true));
    self::__destruct();
    return $rs;
}
```

HTML resumido (exemplo):

```
<?php
 include './inc/database.class.php';
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $PDO = new database();
  $resultado = $PDO->deleteDB("delete from usuario where login = :login and password = :password",array(':login' => "teste",':password' => "1234"));
?>
  <div class="form">
  <!-- inputs -->
  <!-- buttons -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

database.class.php (alteração)

```
public function deleteDB($sql,$params=null){
    $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r("<div class='alert' ... etc>",true));
    self::__destruct();
    return $rs;
}
```

Por fim, pensei em outras formas, ate mesmo em uma nova classe para tratar os erros, mas gostaria de algo simples como o exemplo mostrado acima.
Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço ;)

Comment: `die(string)` encerra a execução, é como o `exit(int)`. Troque `die` por `echo "<div ...>"`.

Comment: Mas desta forma a conexão permaneceria ativa, isso seria adequado?

Comment: Não, não. O `die` não encerra a conexão. O `die` encerra a aplicação, consequentemente a conexão. Em todo caso, você quer encerrar somente a conexão, não sua aplicação. Veja [To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted—you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).